# What kind of sound frequency which can be audible in speaker but cant be recorded & playback

Tags: microphone, recording, sound, speakers

What kind of sound frequency which can be audible in speaker but cant be recorded & playback.
I want to send a sound file which can be listen by receiver but cant be recorded for future playback use.

Comment: What you are suggesting is impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. If a sound can be played back by an ordinary speaker, it can be picked up by a microphone.